# Machine learning algorithms for identification and classification of Microorganisms

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, computer-vision, image-recognition

https://www.google.com/search?q=Viruses+images&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiB9-fsoL3sAhUJyHMBHWRZB-sQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=Viruses+images&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQA1AAWABgo_sCaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img&ei=HL6LX4H5DImQz7sP5LKd2A4&bih=592&biw=360&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=inv

https://www.google.com/search?q=bacteria+images&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=inv&sxsrf=ALeKk00Z4XiPIbFDVbfDqZyuAOCSzt6Izw:1602994167858&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4xs7Por3sAhW-7HMBHav0ChEQ_AUoAXoECCQQAQ&biw=360&bih=592&dpr=2

https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Book%3A_Microbiology_(Boundless)/1%3A_Introduction_to_Microbiology/1.2%3A_Microbes_and_the_World/1.2A_Types_of_Microorganisms

Can machine learning classification, computer vision, image processing algorithms assist in identification & segregation of viruses & bacteria microorganisms?

Input Dataset : Images of all viruses and bacteria in gif, jpg formats.

Output : Virus or Bacteria identification with the name, short description.

New updates :

Modify the existing images of all seven types of microorganisms database by adding proper label name with Adobe Photoshop web designing software or any other image editing software.

Examples : COVID-19 virus, Tuberculosis bacteria etc

Inputting images for all seven types of microorganisms viz viruses, bacteria, archaea, protozoa, algae, fungi and multicellular animal parasites.

https://towardsdatascience.com/wtf-is-image-classification-8e78a8235acb

https://www.google.com/search?q=diseases+caused+by+virus&oq=diseases+caused+by+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i59j0i457j0l2.8949j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.com/search?q=diseases+caused+by+bacteria&oq=diseases+caused+by+bac&aqs=chrome.0.0i67i457j0j69i57j0j0i20i263.6814j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.com/search?q=diseases+spread+through+archaea&oq=&aqs=chrome.1.69i176j35i39i362l4...4.-1j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-lava&sxsrf=ALeKk01JWGtJY1ucgsaljZXnB-ulqbL04w%3A1603026074551&ei=mjyMX6uHIZD59QOI7o6ICQ&q=diseases+caused+by+protozoa&oq=diseases+caused+by+protozoa&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEdQAFgAYK42aABwAXgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAyAEIwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-lava&sxsrf=ALeKk01eT0ai8hYeXrtRyEM2c2-WvqukPQ%3A1603025640805&ei=6DqMX-XMMMfJrQGc8IiAAw&q=diseases+caused+through+algae&oq=diseases+causedthrough+algaue&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAEYADIECCEQCjoECAAQRzoECCMQJzoFCAAQyQM6AggAOgYIABAWEB46CQgAEMkDEBYQHjoFCCEQoAE6CAghEBYQHRAeOgcIIRAKEKABOgQIHhAKUM4tWN6HAWCtjwFoAnABeACAAZMCiAHOJpIBBjAuMTcuOZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

https://www.google.com/search?q=diseases+spread+through+fungi&oq=diseases+spread+through+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j35i39j69i59j0i457j0.14735j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.com/search?client=ms-android-lava&sxsrf=ALeKk03dcQw152ejskUp_AQElmXhqLJ3Xw%3A1603026257174&ei=UT2MX9eOCpnorQHc26jYCg&q=diseases+spread+through+multicellular+animal+parasites&oq=diseases+spread+through+multicellular+animal+parasites&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAM6BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BQgAEMkDOgIIADoFCCEQoAFQpA5Y9Ddg9zpoAHABeACAAZIHiAGbHZIBCTItMi4yLjYtM5gBAKABAaABAsgBCMABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can. You would need a labelled dataset of the name of viruses and bacteria with each image. This can then be fed into a CNN with a softmax output. The model can predict the label of the image, and then you could use a database to recall a short description to accompany the prediction.

Comment: Thanks Cameron.